# Ubunt does not start

Tags: boot

I was using ubuntu and windows in dual mode. But suddenly my ubuntu stopped working. As I tried to open ubuntu it wont get open it say something like "udev is not premitted..." 
What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the complete error message you are getting is :

> udevadm trigger is not permitted while udev is unconfigured

If yes, a [fix](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/devmapper/+bug/358654) to this bug has been published. You need to have a live CD/USB and also need to know the failed Ubuntu partition for this to work. To reproduce the code from the link above:

Boot into the live CD/USB and run the following codes (replace `/dev/sda8` with your Ubuntu partition):

```
sudo -i

# create a target mount point
mkdir /mnt/target

# mount root
mount /dev/sda8 /mnt/target
# mount boot
mount /dev/sda9 /mnt/target/boot

chroot /mnt/target/

# update
dpkg --configure -a

# done
exit

#unmount
umount /mnt/target/boot
umount /mnt/target
```

Refer:

1. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/devmapper/+bug/358654
2. http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1567147

Comment: That is exactly the problem but if I will replace it with my ubuntu partition will it effect my windows or data on other drives? Or data that was on ubuntu before?